# Why am I getting this MySQL error in pika python, unread result found

Tags: python, mysql, docker, mysql-connector, pika

getting an unread result found error when executing the bolded sql commands. The python code is in a docker container and so is the MySQL db. Truncating the code to highlight where the issue is.

```
import mysql.connector
from datetime import datetime
import requests
import json
import math
import os
import logging

# Use logging.info() to output info to the console
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Connecting to the MySQL Docker image
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='test', password='test', host='db', database='VisualDB')
logging.info(cnx.is_connected())
# Use mycursor for pointing to tables and making queries<br>
mycursor = cnx.cursor()
userRows = mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM user;")
cnx.commit()
logging.info(userRows)
sensorRows = mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM SENSOR;")
cnx.commit()
logging.info(sensorRows)
```

This is the error I get: `mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found`
Did a bunch of commenting out to confirm these lines are the issue, I also sometimes get it on the `cnx().commit`
Is there something wrong with my image itself? **mysql:latest**
Also the database is created using a Dockerfile in the "db" folder pointing to a sql file

Thank you in advance for any advice you can provide!

Answer (score 1):

`logging.info(userRows)` does **not** consume the results that `mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM user;")` returns, so the next call to `mycursor.execute` will cause the said error.

Try to consume the results, ie `logging.info(list(userRows))`.